# What to do after finding products for coefficients in generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

The problem is as follows:

$\text{Determine the coef. of } x^{10} \text{ in } (x^3 + x^5 + x^6)(x^4 + x^5 + x^7)(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+...)$

With this, there are three ways to get $x^{10}$.
1) $x^3\cdot x^7\cdot1$
2) $x^5\cdot x^5\cdot1$
3) $x^6\cdot x^4\cdot 1$

But then what? I don't understand where to go on from here.

Comment: If you are going to compute it that way; by finding all the ways to multiply the terms in the factors to get the right exponent, then you add those terms and that is the coefficient. There are other approaches for this problem. Notice that each factor is the sum of a geometric progression. You can add them first and them multiply.

Comment: @Pp.. I would like to solve it the way I'm trying to right now. What do you mean, I'd just add them up? Each of those add up to $x^{10}$. Aren't combinations supposed to be involved somewhere? I can't find an example like the problem I've posted anywhere.

Comment: When you multiply $(1+x+x^3)(1+x^2)=1+x^2+x+x^3+x^3+x^5$, you may get repeated terms, like $x^3+x^3$. And then you add them (simplify) to get $1+x^2+2x^3+x^5$. What you have done so far is to find that the term $x^{10}$ can appear from those multiplications you wrote. Now simply. $x^{10}+x^{10}+x^{10}=3x^{10}$.

Comment: @Pp.. Would you happen to know of some good sources to better understand this material? My professor doesn't explain these things well, and I can't find any decent resources on this topic.

Comment: Google for a book called Concrete Mathematics, it is free, and if I remember correctly it has a chapter on generating functions. Googling for generating functions also produce some lecture notes and maybe some books too.

Comment: The answer is $3$ as there are three terms each with a unit coefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_i x_i \sum_j y_j \sum_k z_k = \sum_{i,j,k} x_i y_j z_k$$

Suppose we wanted to multiply $(x_1 + x_2)(y_1 + y_2 + y_3)$. We take every combination of $x_iy_j$ and sum them together. In every possible way, we choose one term from the first bracket, either $x_1$ or $x_2$ and then multiply it by one term from the second bracket, either $y_1$, $y_2$ or $y_3$. Let's look at a picture.

[image]

So how do we multiply $(x^3 + x^5 + x^6) (x^4 + x^5 + x^7) (1 + x^5 + x^{10})$. Doing the same as above, we will get $27$ terms, which is unwieldy. Instead let's just pick out the ones that contribute to $x^{10}$.

$$ 
(x^3 + x^5 + x^6) (x^4 + x^5 + x^7) (1 + x^5 + x^{10}) \\ \; \\
\begin{array}
( &= &... &+& (x^3) (x^7)(1) &+& ... &+& (x^5)(x^5)(1) &+& ... &+& (x^6)(x^4)(1) &+& ... \\ 
 &= &... &+& x^{10} &+& ... &+& x^{10} &+& ... &+& x^{10} &+& ...\\
 &=& ... &+& 3x^{10} &+& ...\\
\end{array}
$$
There is nothing fancy about this calculation; all we are doing is standard multiplication.

---

You linked [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305328/finding-coefficient-of-generating-function). Let's take a look at the product.

$$ (\;)_1 \;\; (\;)_2\;\; (\;)_3\;\; (\;)_4\;\; (\;)_5 = \\
\left(x^{31}\right) \left(1-x^{16}\right) \left(1-x^{15}\right) (1-x^{26}) \left(\sum_{i\geq 0} {k+2 \choose k} x^k \right)
$$

Now we want to find the coefficient of $x^{52}$. I want you to carry it out yourself so you understand. Here is your first exercise: How can we choose one term from each $()_i$ such that their combined product results in $x^{52}$ (ignoring coefficients)? You should find that there are only three ways to do this.

Comment: But how do I know when to do this versus using combinations to determine the coef?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: [See this Math Stack Exchange problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305328/finding-coefficient-of-generating-function). The second answer has you determining the coef with combinations.

Comment: It's the same thing. Notice how I singled out the $x^{10}$ terms. For easy problems like this one you can single them out by inspection. For a harder problem you need to factor first before hoping to single out the terms you want. The bottom line is that we are doing the same thing. We are writing out our multiplication as something manageable, and then by inspection, counting the combinations that contribute to the power of $x$ that we want. Don't try to think of this as a plug and chug. Nothing in combinatorics should ever be plug and chug. You need to think about what you are actually doing

Comment: If you were to do the problem in your example using combinations instead, how would you do it? The thing that confuses me is in the problem I linked, I see where the 21, the 6, and the 5 came from; but, why wasn't the 31, 15, and 16 used in the combinations? It was listed that they were a factor.

Comment: @Nxt3 I added an exercise at the end of my post. See if you can do it.

Comment: I totally understand this stuff now. Thank you so much for your help!